# Quickly getting to local time YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS in Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime, localtime

i want to get local time and formatted as YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS (say 2009-11-29 14:28:29).,
How can i get date in this format YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS ?

i have try

```
my $format = "%4u-%02u-%02u %02u:%02u:%02u";
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime;
printf "$format\n", $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec;
```

the print output is that i want ,but how to designed the output to a variable ??

Comment: What script have you tried/found so far? You need to research and try some code, so when you ask here, you're given constructive advice.

Comment: The answer is `use Time::Piece; print localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');` as a quick search would have told you

Comment: i have try 


    my $format = "%4u-%02u-%02u %02u:%02u:%02u";
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime;
    printf "$format\n", $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec;



the print output is that i want ,but how to designed the output to a variable ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sprintf` instead of `printf`.

```
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = localtime;
my $formatted = sprintf "%4u-%02u-%02u %02u:%02u:%02u",
   $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec;
```

But it's much simpler to use `strftime`.

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );
my $formatted = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime);
```